# MySQL Query for retrieving records with HTML form Checkboxes

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I everyone, I'm a little bit stuck with the following.

I have a HTML form with checkboxes.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="1"/>1 brown<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="2"/>2 blue<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="3"/>3 green<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="4"/>4 red<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="5"/>5 yellow<br>
```

I have a MySQL table as below :

```
 |id|colorids|
 +--+--------+
 |1 |4       |
 |2 |2       |
 |3 |3,1     |
 |4 |1       |
 |5 |2,3     |
 |6 |5       |

 colorids TYPE VARCHAR
```

When I select the box '1 brown' I should get the result id 4, this is no problem. Or box '1 brown' and '5 yellow', I get id 4 and id 6, also no problem.

But when I select the boxes '2 blue' and '3 green' and '5 yellow' I want the get the result : id 2, id 3, id 5, id 6

Now this I don't know how to do.

If there is just one value in colorids, this query works fine.

```
    <cfquery name="qGetColors" datasource="#application.dsn#">
            SELECT *
            FROM
                    colors
            WHERE        
                    colorids IN (#form.colors#);
    </cfquery>
```

What query should I use to get what I want when I there are multiple boxes selected and more than one value in de colorids column?

Would I need to use something with 'find_in_set'? If so how would the query be with the form list 'colors'?

Many thanks for any help or directions. I'm using Coldfusion, but the query is the issue.

Comment: You should normalize your database to have a table with each ID and colorid.

Comment: The reason you are having difficulty figuring out the query is because databases are not designed to work with "lists". They are designed to work with sets (or rows) of data. While you could technically use [hacks like `find_in_set`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437697/sql-query-multiple-tables-with-multiple-joins-and-column-field-with-comma-seper/25437961#25437961) - you shouldn't. They are just poor substitutes for creating the proper table structure. Instead, normalize the tables and queries like this will be simple.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions! Really appreciate it. I guess that my database knowledge is not so good. Any suggestions on how I should normalize the database to achieve what I want?

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Sounds like you are working with a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship.  See [Storing IDs as comma separated values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944754/storing-ids-as-comma-separated-values/9946106#9946106) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

as @Matt Busche said, you want another table, something like this;

```
|id|other_id|colorids|
+--+--------+--------+
|1 |1       |4
|2 |2       |2
|3 |3       |3
|4 |3       |1
|5 |4       |1
|6 |5       |2
|7 |5       |3
|8 |6       |5
```

then you can easily `select other_id where colourids IN (<CFQUERYPARAM VALUE="#form.colors#" CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" LIST="YES">)` linking other_id to your id in the original table

the cfqueryparam helps protect against sql injection